# Renumbering line by line

Tags: python

I have an input text which looks like this:

```
word77 text text bla66 word78 text bla67
text bla68 word79 text bla69 word80 text
bla77 word81 text bla78 word92 text bla79 word99
```

I have to renumber `word` and `bla`  from 1, in each line.

I can renumber the whole input which looks like this:

```
word1 text text bla1 word2 text bla2
text bla3 word3 text bla4 word4 text
bla5 word5 text bla6 word6 text bla7 word7
```

The code for the above:

```
import re
def replace(m): global i; i+=1; return str(i);
fp = open('input.txt', 'r').read()
i = 0
fp = re.sub(r'(?<=word)(\d+)', replace, fp)
i = 0
fp = re.sub(r'(?<=bla)(\d+)', replace, fp)
#open('sample.txt', 'wb').write(fp)
print fp
```

Ideally, the result should look like this:

```
word1 text text bla1 word2 text bla2
text bla1 word1 text bla2 word2 text
bla1 word2 text bla3 word3 text bla4 word4
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You operate on the whole file at once (`fp.read()`) - you need to do it line-wise:

```
with open("input.txt","w") as f:
    f.write("""word77 text text bla66 word78 text bla67
text bla68 word79 text bla69 word80 text
bla77 word81 text bla78 word92 text bla79 word99""")

import re

i = 0

def replace(m): 
    global i 
    i+=1
    return str(i)

with open('input.txt') as fp, open("output.txt","w") as out:
    # read only one line of the file and apply the transformations
    for line in fp:
        i = 0
        l = re.sub(r'(?<=word)(\d+)', replace, line)
        i = 0
        l = re.sub(r'(?<=bla)(\d+)', replace, l)
        out.write(l)

with open("output.txt") as f:
    print(f.read())
```

Output:

```
word1 text text bla1 word2 text bla2
text bla1 word1 text bla2 word2 text
bla1 word1 text bla2 word2 text bla3 word3
```

Answer (score 0):

We can create a more generic function that renumbers any number of words. Each word to replace gets its own associated counter, and we do all in one pass with `re.sub`:

```
import re
from itertools import count


data = """word77 text text bla66 word78 text bla67
text bla68 word79 text bla69 word80 text
bla77 word81 text bla78 word92 text bla79 word99"""

words_to_renumber = ['word', 'bla']

def renumber(words_to_renumber, data):
    counters = {word:count(1) for word in words_to_renumber}
    def replace(match):
        word = match.group(1)
        return word + str(next(counters[word]))

    rep_re = re.compile('(' + '|'.join(words_to_renumber) + ')' + '\d+')
    out = rep_re.sub(replace, data)
    return out

print(renumber(words_to_renumber, data))
```

Output:

```
word1 text text bla1 word2 text bla2
text bla3 word3 text bla4 word4 text
bla5 word5 text bla6 word6 text bla7 word7
```